# Webpack & React With Es2015 Modules via Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Im really struggling with Webpack & React. It seems for ages, Node 5.0 was not registering the npm modules I installed in the package.json 'dependencies'.
Today, I upgraded Node to 5.2 and it seems to be chugging along fine now.

However, now Im struggling with getting React code in modules to work.

Webpack doesn't report any error.
Chrome Console says:

"Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element." (which is pointing to Main.jsx file).

There is a lot of dependencies & my webpack config is fairly lengthy so I hesitantly post the main.jsx file content here only on SO. The whole repo (with length config files, however, the React code itself is a few lines long) is [here on Bitbucket](https://kay2dan@bitbucket.org/kay2dan/test_webpack_build.git).

main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppParent from './components/App.jsx';
main ();
function main () {
    const app = document.createElement ('div');
    document.body.appendChild (app);
    ReactDOM.render (AppParent, app);
};
```

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Topbar from './Topbar.jsx';
export default AppParent;
var AppParent = React.createClass ({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div className = 'ReactParent'>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: My immediate guess is that this is caused by exporting AppParent before you define it in App.jsx. I can test it in a Codepen when I'm at my laptop.

Comment: Just tried it and no. That didn't make a difference. I think I read that the import & exports are hoisted to the top.

Comment: @BrandonLewis is correct, your current ordering for exports is also incorrect. The "hoisting" behavior of exports doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: BrandonLewis & @loganfsmyth, yes you are correct, moving them to after the declaration makes the export func work. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`render`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render) method you need to render an element:

```
ReactDOM.render (<AppParent />, app);
```

You are passing a [React component class](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createclass).

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering an element it should be  `ReactDom.render(<AppParent />, app)`